# How can I regenerate the QR code used for 2FA on GitHub?

Tags: github

I did 2FA authentication for GitHub before, but I broke my smartphone with the Authentification App on it, and I am trying to do 2FA authentication for GitHub again with a new smartphone.

However, when I go to the 2FA Settings section of GitHub on the web, it asks for a TOTP code, and I cannot restore it on the new smartphone.

If I could only output the 2FA QR code from GitHub on the web, the problem would be solved, but does anyone know how to reset the 2FA information on GitHub?

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

I tried to see if I could re-print the QR code or reset the 2FA authentication on the "Password and Authentication" page in the Settings section of GitHub on the web.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was in such a hurry that I overlooked a simple thing.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Re-enable GitHub two-factor authentication with Authenticator app when switching to a new smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77693912/967621)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've lost access to your 2FA (Two-Factor Authentication) codes on GitHub due to losing your smartphone, you can typically regain access by using the recovery codes that you generated when setting up 2FA. If you didn't save these codes, you should contact GitHub support for further assistance